# Problem installing Ubuntu 15.04

Tags: partitioning, system-installation

I have installed Ubuntu before but then I try to install Ubuntu 15.04 on a Asus computer I am getting a new message I never got before. It reads like this:

> If you continue, the changes listed below will be written to the
>   disks. Otherwise you will be able to make further changes manually. 
>   WARNING: This will destroy all data on any parttions you have removed
>   as well as on the partitions that are going to be formatted.
>
> The partition tables of the following devices are changed: SCSI1
>   (0,0,0) (sda)
>
> The following partitions are going to be formatted: partition #1 of
>   SCSI1 (0,0,0) (sda) as ext4 partition #5 of SCSI1 (0,0,0 (sda) sd swap

I dont know what this means and a friend of my told me his computer stoped working then he got a message like this. What am I to do?

Comment: It looks like you are about to erase everything in the computer and install Ubuntu. Any data, photos, music, as well as Windows or any other OS will be destroyed.

Comment: I want to make a complete installation and I have done that before but never got a message like this before.

Comment: Can you take a screenshot/ photo of the error and [edit](http://askubuntu.com/posts/620256/edit) the original question and put a link there?

Comment: This sounds very similar to the bug report I filed about installing on my Asus: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubiquity/+bug/1389081

Answer (score 0):

Don't take my word for it, but.. 
If you selected the install Ubuntu on the entire disk, the system will have to format them before installing your OS hence the message.

If there is anything on the disk that you require then you should select "other" and don't mark the format button on the partitions that have data you want to keep.

I usually work with a minimum of three partitions - root-  / home - /home and swap and only format the root partition.

Comment: I think i messed up my computer. It is not working. Then i try to login i keep getting sent back to the login. What went wrong?